# pycharm interpreter using cygwin version python

Tags: python, django, windows, redis, pycharm

I am running django python2.7 using Pycharm in windows.
Now I have some issue with redis queue not working in windows because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17301045/6041708)

I am trying to do what this person did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33318875/6041708). Use a cygwin version of python as pycharm interpreter.

(not sure if I downloaded all the packages or did correct steps)
I downloaded cygwin and install packages python2.7 + python-setuptools and then try to point my Pycharm interpreter to c:/cygwin/bin/python27.exe

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em2V2.jpg)

After that it seem ok and ask me to install packing tools pip, I clicked it and it give me this error:

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhzzE.jpg)

"Cannot start process, the working directory '\cygdrive\c\Users\User1G~1.SIS\AppData\Local\Temp\1\tmpYpudf2pycharm-management\pip-7.1.0' does not exist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message it looks like pip can't be found... Are you sure you have installed pip?

Take a look here, how you can install pip: [Installing Pip-3.2 on Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641438/installing-pip-3-2-on-cygwin)

You can open a cygwin command line window and try to manually install the packages you want to.